# In a Hotwire/Rails app, how to force a form helper to accept only text/html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, hotwire-rails

I've incorporated Hotwire into my latest Rails 6 app. The Hotwire/Turbo portions are working great, but I have a plain user form that I don't want to use Hotwire/Turbo for. Currently, all form submissions are hitting `format.turbo_stream {}` in my controller , but I want this particular form to hit the `format.html {}` block instead. I noticed that the `Accept` header on form submission requests automatically includes `text/vnd.turbo_stream.html` now, but I'm not sure how to remove this.

The form is not wrapped in a turbo_frame_tag; there is no Turbo anywhere on the page, and it looks pretty standard:

```
    <%= form_with model: @user do |f| %>
      <%= f.file_field :avatar, class: "file-input", id: "avatar-input" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: "input wide", placeholder: "Your name here" %>

      <%= f.submit "Next", class: "button-next-submit" %>
    <% end %>
```

How do I force this change on a per-form basis? I previously thought that adding the turbo tags was how you change the behavior / the Accept header, but I see now that once you add a `format.turbo_stream` block in your controller method, the form begins to prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. It looks like most form helpers (`form_with`, `form_for`, etc) accept a `format` param in the option hash ([documentation link](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)). The value you provide should match the `format.x` block you wish to hit in your controller. E.g.:

```
# view.html.erb
<%= form_with model: @user, format: :html do |f| %>
...
<% end %>

# controller.rb

def update
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {} # format: :html will hit this
    format.turbo_stream {} # format: :turbo_stream will hit this
    # format.json is also an option
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case (rails 7) `format: :html` wasn't enough. What works for me was `turbo: false`

```
# view.html.erb
<%= form_with model: @user, data: { turbo: false } do |f| %>
...
<% end %>

# controller.rb

def update
  ...
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {} # format: :html will hit this
    format.turbo_stream {} # format: :turbo_stream will hit this
    # format.json is also an option
  end
end
```

Comment: This also works with link_to to prevent turbo requests if you have links inside of the turbo frame.